# I charge my iPad mini and I start to turn it on showing a screen that my iPad is charging but it turn off

Tags: ipad, battery

My iPad mini went dead because I didn't charge it while I'm playing with only 2 percent. I started to charge it and for a few hours I start to turn it on. The screen shows that my iPad is charging but the battery doesn't change it just it starts at the beginning (I don't know how to describe this). Then it turn off I noticed that when it turn off the screen would flash a white screen quickly with a black line in the middle of my iPad horizontally. I have been charging it for a few hours maybe between 6 - 7 hours and it was still doing the same thing. I need my iPad for school and my mom would beat my butt if she knews. Can you help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an Apple original or MFi certified charger and cable? The charging circuits built into Apple iDevices can be damaged by cheap chargers. They will give the appearance of charging, what we call "fake charging" but not really charging at all. This usually requires a logic board level repair.

However in your case, it may just be a dead battery as the iPad mini is an old device and the battery may have just up and died after you let it deplete down to near 0%. You shouldn't worry about getting your butt kicked...these things happen. You should tell them the battery appears to be dead and if they never had it replaced, they should consider bringing it into a repair shop for a battery replacement.

Comment: It was a mini iPad 4 by the way and it's ok now my problem all along was a low voltage. I was charging on a wire and then 1 day passed I decided to charge on the wall socket then it appears it was charging. So I'm gonna delete my question